# Dockerized Python with conda libs (numpy, pandas) and hmmlearn, psycopg2 Image on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-2.7, dockerfile, raspbian, miniconda

I am trying to run analytics written in Python using Data Science libraries (numpy, pandas, scipy, etc) in docker on Raspberry Pi (armv7l). 
Along with that I need to install hmmlearn, psycopg2, etc libs. 
I am using the installation from http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh. Do we have any docker image which I can use ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one i am using which comes with preloaded python numpy and ready for TensorFlow package or any other ML work that requires latest compiled python:

Docker Image: https://hub.docker.com/r/mostafae/rpi-stretch/

Docker files repo: https://github.com/melzoghbi/docker

Hope this helps.